# Serialize item in base of condition using XmlSerializer c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I've an object which has one of its parameters a List of objects.

Example, a Student object with a List of Exams:

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [XmlArray("Exams")]
    public List<Exam> Exams {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Exam
{
    [XmlAttribute("Course")]
    public string Course;

    [XmlAttribute("Score")]
    public int Score;
}
```

My goal is to serialize the Student model and include into the XML only the Exams satisfying some criteria, example I would like only the Exams with low ( < 5) score.

Can this kind of operation be done using XmlSerializer present into `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace?

Comment: minor note: `[Serializable]` doesn't impact `XmlSerializer` in any way - you can remove it (unless you're also using `BinaryFormatter` somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a student with satisfying exams score using a LINQ query and then serialize the result

```
var studentToSerialize = new Student { 
           Name = student.Name,
           Exams = student.Exams.where(e => e.Score < 5)
    }
// Your serialization logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any serializer that offers "per collection element" conditional serialization; some do "per property" conditional serialization, but ... not this. The simplest thing would be to create a *copy* of the student with just the items you want to serialize. The more complicated approach would be to write some kind of custom `IList<Exam>` shim that wraps the same `List<Exam>` instance and applies filtering, but... that's all kinds of ugly, and I strongly recommend not trying to do that (problems, for example: what happens if `Add` is called on the wrapper type, and the element being added has a high score?).

So my suggestion would be to filter *before* serializing - either by removing the unwanted items, or by creating a clone with just the desired items.